# Django Upload Images from Forms

Tags: python, django

I am trying to upload the images from django widget form. The rest of the form is filed correctly but the image field shows errors. Despite using the request.FILES is still getting the error.
What could be the problem
Here is my views.py file

```
def addProduct(request):
    form = ProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('modifyAllProduct')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'products/Admin/addProduct.html', context)
```

Here is my form.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['image', 'title', 'category', 'price',
                           'description', 'is_published']
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

            'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_published': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        }
```

Here is my model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    delivery_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
```

Comment: Can you show your template

Comment: Thsnks, i was missing the enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not provided this following code `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
in your HTML form tag?

Answer (score 0):

Oh community, have just remembered i didn't put enctype="multipart/form-data"   `<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">` Le it help someone